# Can't find a line of code that appears in the developer tools

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I'm trying to find a line of code but I can't find it.

I have a lightbox, when this lightbox is activated, the overlay opens at this moment, some lines of code appear in the developer tools (I use Chrome). Among this lines, one interests me, but I can't find this line in all my documents (HTML, PHP, CSS, Scripts).

Do you have any ideas how I can find it? (CTRL + F doesn't find it)

Maybe the developer tools can save over the document concerned ?

Comment: It's got to be there somewhere, there's not a whole lot we can do as we aren't actually seeing it.  All I can say is the file structure should match up, the debugger should display what file it is reading from, and if it is a virtual file that means it was externally generated (you can tell if the file name is surrounded by parentheses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I find it, it was about a script.
I used a 'packed' file, I couldn't see this lines of code because all was compressed by jQuery.
All I have to do is to open the original script and to change settings.
Hope it will help someone else.